# Can I locally emulate cloud function and hosting at the same time?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I am writing a simple web app with firebase hosting and cloud functions. My functions are onCreate , onDelete and httpsServer. I wan't to test my app by running it locally. How can I do this since `firebase serve` only works with https function and hosting.

I have tried running `firebase serve` and `firebase functions:shell` at the same time on different bash terminals. This causes `firebase functions:shell` to fail.

**The create function** :

```
exports.created = functions.firestore.document('Books/{bookID}')
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {

          FUNCTION_BODY
     });
```

**The Delete Function** :

```
exports.deleted = functions.firestore.document('Books/{bookID}')
    .onDelete((snapshot, context) => {

         FUNCTION_BODY
    });
```

**The https Function** :

```
exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

**The error thrown from bash** :

```
$ firebase functions:shell
i  functions: Preparing to emulate functions.
Warning: You're using Node.js v10.13.0 but Google Cloud Functions only supports v6.11.5.
!  functions: Failed to emulate created
!  functions: Failed to emulate deleted
!  functions: Failed to emulate app
i  functions: No functions to emulate.
No functions emulated.
```

**Output from second bash** :

```
i  functions: Preparing to emulate functions.
Warning: You're using Node.js v10.13.0 but Google Cloud Functions only supports v6.11.5.
i  hosting: Serving hosting files from: public
+  hosting: Local server: http://localhost:5000
info: initalised
info: rendering home...
+  functions: app: http://localhost:5001/book-shelf-be347/us-central1/app
info: Worker for app closed due to file changes.
```

**Note**: *These are separate bash terminals running at the same time on the same machine.*

Comment: If it is not possible with fire-base tools other alternatives will work.

Comment: Maybe something similar to nodemon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some digging through the firebase documentation and could not find any solution. This is probably because there is no official tools that let you do this. So I finally solved the problem by running the hosting using nodemon and then using

> firebase serve --functions

This solved the problem of using same port since it is handled by nodemon.

Hope firebase will provide new tools in the future.